# python design pattern for abstracting data access: advantages, disadvantages?

Tags: python, design-patterns

I was wondering for a few ways to accomplish abstracting the data storage access away from the main application and a small example, an IoC framework seems overkill, maybe passing object via constructor parameter (facade).

is the below pseudo-code a good way to do things and how do i fill in the missing pieces with python?

```
main.py
    resp = Repository(engine=NoSql)  # can easily switch to nosql???
    resp.save("hello");
    resp.select("hello");

repository.py
class Repository:
    def __init__(self, engine):
        self.engine = engine

    def save(self, str)
        engine.save(str)

    def select(self, str)
        engine.select(str)

nosql.py
class NoSql:
    def save(self, str)
        nosql.save(str)

    def select(self, str)
        nosql.select(str)

mysql.py
class MySql:
    def save(self, str)
        mysql.save(str)

    def select(self, str)
        mysql.select(str)
```

Comment: you've missed the `self` argument on every method...

Comment: @JBernardo "the below pseudo-code..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the above isn't a great way to go about it. The consumer (in this case `main.py`) shouldn't know anything about the model's implementation details. What I might do is store key/value pairs in an external configuration file to be used by the model to determine the engine to use.

Comment: so you say go the IoC route?  Something has to create the instance of a storage engine.  If so do you have any suggestions for frameworks or code snippets to use?  Or homebrew?

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty much the same implementation that SQLAlchemy uses and is quite effective imho.

Comment: do you think that is overkill in python if the likely hood of changing storage options in very low and would require many other environment (deployment) changes?

Comment: Haha.. I had started to edit my answer saying exactly that. Yes, I think it's overkill. The only times that I could see changing databases to be valid is if you wanted to move from a legacy relational database such as MySQL to a NoSQL database, in which case your models would most likely need to be changed anyways. I think that it's a good idea if you're developing something such as SQLAlchemy, but a little overkill if it's just for your app.

Comment: i guess python facade (Repository) pattern, if let's say only one storage will be used.  Just a way to abstract it from the main program.  I am not sure of the correct python way to do it, pythonic, right?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a reason that you're *not* using SQLAlchemy for your app? I would *strongly* recommend it.

Comment: not really, would that be as performant as using let's say the mysqldb library directly or the tornado.database library?  It's a small simple app wanted to reduce the bloat factor.

Comment: The minimal amount of overhead incurred by using the library *FAR* outweighs the cost of writing your own handlers and trapping edge cases. SQLAlchemy is pretty much (AFAIK) the defacto standard for database access in Python applications that use relational database backends. Also, if it's a simple app, then there's really no need to worry about a few cycles that could have been saved :)

Comment: would you suggest using this for writing a restful api going directly against a database?

Answer (score 2):

You're about to create Yet Another ORM layer.

Rather than waste a lot of time reinventing that wheel, learn about existing ORM, and adapt one to your noSQL database engine of choice.

Start, for example, with SQLAlchemy as an ORM that can do all of what you want (and more) for SQL.

Because of Python's duck typing you can invent a compatible noSQL ORM or Repository ORM or anything else you think is important.

Do not, however, reinvent this wheel from scratch.  Read a few other implementations.  SQLObject, Django ORM, SQLAlchemy are good places to start.

Comment: @dre: "i wouldn't be using the true power of an orm".  False.  You already are using that power.  The "overkill" is what everyone says to justify writing yet another copy  of an existing framework.  "Read a few other implementations".  Please.

Comment: @dre: "not every application written calls for using an orm."  What?  I'm not making any claim that all applications need an ORM.  I'm making the claim that your requirements **are** an ORM and you should very carefully read at least three existing ORM's before doing another thing.  "writing a new framework is a waste of time".  It often is.  It's an "attractive nuisance" as the lawyers say.  Please read at least three other implementations.  Please.

Comment: @dre: "abstracting the data storage access away from the main application" is not a requirement?  What is it then?  A suggestion? If so, what's the actual requirement in this question?

Comment: @dre: I thought I provided some ideas.  You seem to have a lot of objections for someone looking for ideas.  I guess your idea of looking for ideas is to object to the ideas; I'm not sure what that means.

Comment: @dre: My point is to present my idea.  Other people have other answers with other ideas.  Your negative comments ("seem overkill", "i wouldn't be using the true power of an orm") indicate that you are not actually open to ideas, but were merely looking for confirmation of the position you established in your question.  As an answer, I don't need to be open to anything.  I'm providing an answer.  If you have additional or different requirements, please **update** the question.

Comment: @dre: (Sigh).  If my answer wasn't the *right* answer, I wouldn't have provided it.  Your job is not to talk me out of my answer.  I'm defending my answer because you asked for help.  I'm providing help.   Talking me out of the help I'm offering is silly.  Just ignore it.  Or fix your requirements.  If you want information on "performance, bloat, complexity, reliability,". You should actually ask those actual questions instead of saying that it's "overkill".  Saying it's "overkill" is dismissive and negative.  It's not a request for clarification.  It's not a question.  It's a statement.

Comment: @dre: You asked, I answered.  Therefore, my answer is -- to me -- right.  I'm unwilling to change it because it's right.  It's as right as it can be given your original question.  You do not talk about "pros and cons" that I can see and you don't **ask** for follow-up in formation.  "many times asking about performance?"  Where?  Please either (a) point out the questions or (b) actually ask for follow-up information.  I am providing all the information you have actually asked for.  Do you want more information?  If so, please actually ask an actual question.  I'm trying to answer questions.

Comment: @dre: Are you asking for advantages and disadvantages?  Is that the point of all the comments?  Is that what you want?  "should just take your answer".  What?  There are multiple answers.  You can ignore answers.  There are comments.  You can ask for clarification.  "if people don't fully agree with you"?  No one can every fully agree with me.  However, you can ask for clarification.  Is that what you want? What clarification do you need?  I don't know what clarification you need.  I'm not you.  Please ask a question so I can provide more information.

Answer (score 0):

That's a workable solution, I've done similar things on other projects.  Make sure you keep all the database implementation in the database classes.  main should be able to switch between the two without any changes.  If you need to make changes to main when switching, that's probably code that should be in the Sql classes.

I would make Repository a base class that the others derive from instead of a wrapper.  That way if two implementations have identical or very similar code you can move parts into Repository so you don't have to duplicate it.